# Realurl generating non default language titles in the url of default tt_news links

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, tt-news

I am using TYPO3 7.6.9, tt_news 7.6.1 and realurl 2.0.14 .
I've configured my realurl manually for my multi-language website. The problem is that, real url is generating non-default language titles for news items in the site at default view.
For instance, my default language is bosnian and alternate translation is english. 
When I view the page like www.mysite.com/bs/article/news.. url is cool.
But when the url is www.mysite.com/article/news.. then the translation of news title is not shown. Instead english title is shown in url.
Already wrote every possible realurl_conf. :( But still pulling my hair out.

```
 'postVarSets' => array (
  '_DEFAULT' => array (
    'article' => array(
       'news' => array (
        'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[tt_news]',
        'lookUpTable' => array(
          'table' => 'tt_news',
          'id_field' => 'uid',
          'alias_field' => 'title',
          'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted AND NOT hidden',
          'useUniqueCache' => 1,
          'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
              'strtolower' => 1,
              'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            ),
          'expireDays' => 180,
          'languageGetVar' => 'L',
          'languageExceptionUids' => '',
          'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
          'transOrigPointerField' => 'l18n_parent',
          // 'autoUpdate' => 1,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Typoscript is like below

```
# language configuration
page.config.linkVars = L
page.config.sys_language_uid = 30
page.config.language = bs
page.config.locale_all = bs_BA.utf8

# english language
[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
page.config.sys_language_uid = 0
page.config.language = en
page.config.locale_all = en_GB.utf8
page.config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[global]
```

I am aware that, during default view no 'L' parameter is passed and all. But with the shared realurl_conf it must be solved,right ?? 
I've tried valueDefault in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no answer to my question yet, I've somehow managed to fix this issue. I know this is quite vague, but I fiiirmly believe the fix came from some typoscript defining the languages. Anyways t is cool now (at least for my website).

Next time you come across an issue like this, try checking your language related typoscript settings. Good Luck Amigos. Peace. :)